# how to get stylometric feature from text( for task of author attribution)

Tags: python, nlp, multiclass-classification

I try to get text features for stylometry task in identifying the author of the given text.
I check for :

- text length by word
- text length by character
- punctuation count
- unique word count
  etc...
  but in classifying this feature give unreasonable results, so:
  i want to check more features...
  I have two questions:

1. Is there any good feature that I forget to extract from text to help classifying result
2. I have a data frame like this:
   text ,                  author ,    pos
   i go to school   ,        x  ,       [N,V,...]
   ..
   we are good   ,     y      ,    [N,V,ADj]

my question is that how can I get good feature from pos column? for example the ratio of "N" to other? or some thing like this...
how to improve this multi_input single_lable multi_class classification result? with which feature? is there any good source?

Comment: try to do it in deep learning approaches like cnn and attention.. see it as classification task :)

Answer (score 1):

Many studies have shown that the frequency and distribution of FUNCTION WORDS is significant and indicative of individual style. FUNCTION WORDS are those with little or no LEXICAL MEANING: articles THE, AN, A, conjunctions, personal pronouns, auxiliary verbs. etc.